# MySQL Workbench replace data in column

Tags: mysql, database-migration, workbench

I have a table in my db called "1_users". That table has a column named "origin". I have imported another table into the same db called "old_users" with an almost identical layout (older version). The old table also features a column named "origin".

What I need now is to replace the data in column "origin" in "1_users" with data in column "origin" in "old_users". Both tables have a column "id" which is identical and can serve as reference.

I am an absolute mysql beginner and do not know sql syntax, but can learn fast if you can show me the basic idea. I work in  mysql workbench.

Thank you in advance, anything helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by joining both tables with id column and update origin in 1_user from old_users.

```
update 1_users
inner join old_users on 1_users.id=old_users.id
set  1_users.origin=old_users.origin;
```

Comment: thanks! Had to set workbench to unsafe mode, but then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to replace data of "1_users" table with data in "old_users",
you can truncate "1_users" data and copy paste all the records of "old_users" data in it (it won't matter if your ID field have same values in both the tables, but if you have additional fields in "1_users" table which you want to maintain then truncation should not be followed).

If table "1_users" has additional column fields which you want to maintain then set field "origin" in "1_users" table to NULL and then update this table with values of "old_users" "origin" field values.

Answer (score 0):

You can update new table "1_users" from old table "old_users", like this:

```
UPDATE 1_users
SET 1_users.origin = (SELECT origin FROM old_users WHERE ID = 1_users.ID)
```

or, if just only two column, you can delete data in "1_users" where ID in ID of "old_users", then INSERT data from "old_users" to "1_users" (but not recommend)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table "1_users" already has some data in its "origin" field and you want to do a replace operation by copying data from the same field of "old_users" by comparing the "id" fields of both tables, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE 1_users 
SET origin = old_users.origin 
FROM old_users 
WHERE old_users.id = 1_users.id;
```

If the target table is currently empty then you should use an INSERT instead:

```
INSERT INTO 1_users (origin)
SELECT origin FROM old_users;
```

If all the fields of "1_users" and "old_users" are the same and the data required in "1_users" is also the same as that of "old_users", you can simply drop the table "1_users" and rename "old_users" to "1_users".

```
DROP TABLE 1_users;
RENAME TABLE old_users TO 1_users;
```